# How to create an error table that only logs last 100 entries

Tags: sql, derby

Is there a way to create a simple ERROR table that only logs the last 100 entries or do I have to write sql that after an insert, deletes any entries older than number 100?

I am using a derby database in the java project.

Comment: Why would you want to limit such a table to only 100 entries, when you can easily fetch the 100 most recent entries?

Comment: It could be 1000 or more. But most important is just to limit the size if I let the program run for days. Then I would be mostly interested in the newest entries.

Comment: It still seems like you should keep all the entries, at least until you have evidence that keeping all the entries is causing you a problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
 delete from table 
 where row_number() over (order by id desc)<100
```

Schedule this to run via SQL Server Agent every 15 mins or so and you will always have top 100 entries in the table.